# What's the analogue of .Net Buffer.BlockCopy in Pure C?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm porting a .Net app to Objective-C and need to add a piece of Pure C code. I have a byte (or char) array and need to copy an amount of bytes with offset to different char array. On .Net that's the Buffer.BlockCopy method:

```cs
Buffer.BlockCopy(sourceArray, sourceOffset, resultArray, resultOffset, length);
```

How can I do this on pure C, if I have two arrays, offsets and length values? Unfortunately, I'm not good enough with pure C and the native Objective-C bytearray work is based on it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. Both solutions work.

Comment: memmove is less efficient than memcpy, and you don't need memmove unless your source and target overlap, which is sure not to be the case here unless sourceArray and resultArray are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the arrays really are different, i.e. there's no overlap, you should use the standard library function [`memcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) to do this.

It takes only three arguments:

- A destination pointer
- A source pointer
- A byte count

You can compute the pointers from your buffer base addresses and offsets. Something like this:

```
void BlockCopy(const uint8_t *source, size_t sourceOffset,
               uint8_t *result, size_t resultOffset,
               size_t length)
{
  memcpy(result + resultOffset, source + sourceOffset, length);
}
```

Of course, all the lengths and offsets must be valid, or you'll attempt to overwrite random memory and get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `memmove`:

```
memmove(resultArray + resultOffset, sourceArray + sourceOffset, length);
```

Note the destination comes first.

If you can say with certainty that the arrays don't overlap you can use `memcpy` instead of `memmove`.

Comment: Unless resultArray is the same as sourceArray in the C# source, they can't overlap.

Comment: @JimBalter Agreed. I just thought it's useful to mention the distinction between `memmove` and `memcpy`. The choice programmer shouldn't have to choose between correctness and efficiency... but often has to.